# Hide Table Row based on an Input Value of From Element

Tags: jquery, html-table

I am facing a situation where a there is a table row with a from element (Radio Button) in it. This table row doesn't have id or class so that I could hide it. (Table is generated at server end with no access.)

I wanted to know if we can hide a table row based on the value of a from element which is inside this table row.

Can I hide this row (TR) by using the VALUE Custom_03 of Radio Button?

Note: I cannot use Field_39 in this case because here it's a group radio buttons. So, I have to go with the VALUE of the element.

```
<tr valign="top" style="width: 400px; ">
<td style="width: 400px; ">
<input id="FIELD_39" type="radio" checked="" name="FIELD_39" value="Custom_03">
<span>Envelopes: £ 0.00</span>
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: When you want to hide table row? based on value or what?

Comment: What's a "from element"? Do you mean "form element"?

Comment: Yes @Sadikhasan want to hide table row based on VALUE or the input field.

Comment: $('#FIELD_39').closest('tr').hide() ?

Comment: @Barmar From element can be Radio Button, Text Box or any other form elements.

Comment: @SSA I have a group radio buttons so I cannot use ID of the element. If I use ID all the rows with radio button will be hidden.

Comment: What do you mean by form element? all input types ? Can you show more markup. $('input[type=text], input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio]').closest('tr').hide();

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery DOM traversal methods to find the `<tr>` that contains the radio button.

```
$(":radio[value=Custom_03]").closest("tr").hide();
```